# I need to ensure an Android service runs once a day for a year

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have a simple app that delivers a motivational quote via a Notification to a user once a day. When clicking on the notification the user is taken to an activity that displays the quote.

The main activity has no gui, it launches Serv1 then calls finish(). The word1 class  is really simple , it has a String Array of quotes , it checks the day of the year , and then goes to that index and displays the quote.

I think the Android system can pretty much kill whatever it wants, whenever it wants when it needs more memory. I thought my options could be

1. Make it a foreground service, which the user is aware of and therefore not an option for the system to kill?
2. Use the start sticky, I checked my phone in Settings->dev options-> process stats and I saw Serv1 running for about 4 days , but today its not there. Is there a list that the system keeps for start sticky? how long between when it gets killed to when it restarts. That is if i am using it correctly in m code.
3. or have it turn on periodically? via a broadcastReciever that checksif it is running.. this is where it gets a little fuzzy , cause what if this gets killed?

im fairly new to Android so any help would be great...

```
public class Serv1 extends Service {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 18);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Serv1.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Serv1.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this
            .getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            pendingIntent);
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

}

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
 Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
 context.startService(service1);

}
```

}

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
  }


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), Word.class);
    PendingIntent showWord = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker("Daily Word").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Daily Word")
            .setContentText("Your Word is ready")
            .setContentIntent(showWord).setAutoCancel(true).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    stopSelf();

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you can achieve something like this using google cloud messaging, you can send it from your server and control the time when it will send, but you still can't force the user to click it.

Comment: Use alarm manager. http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

Comment: im using the alarm manager , im just not sure of a way to ensure it runs basically forever, or untill the user uninstalls the app.

Comment: google cloud messaging looks pretty cool, i will check that out , thanks Tiago

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class RefreshService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

     private AudioManager mAudioManager;
private DbAdapter mDbHelper;
private String user = null;
private String pass = null;

public class RefreshBinder extends Binder {
    RefreshService getService() {
        return RefreshService.this;
    }
}

private static final int MAXIMUM_NOTIFY_EVENTS = 7;

private final IBinder binder = new RefreshBinder();

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private final Runnable refresher = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        refresh();
    }

};

private final Runnable worker= new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doWork();
    }

};

private BroadcastReceiver screenOffReceiver;

private boolean screenOn = true;

private BroadcastReceiver screenOnReceiver;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.i(RefreshService.class.getName(), "onBind");
    return binder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    screenOnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("RefreshService", "Screen on");
            refresh();
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(screenOnReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));

    screenOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("RefreshService", "Screen off");

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(screenOffReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));


    scheduleNext();
    scheduleNextPost();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(RefreshService.class.getName(), "onDestroy");
    if (screenOnReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(screenOnReceiver);
    }
    if (screenOffReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(screenOffReceiver);
    }
    if (handler != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(refresher);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent arg) {
    Log.i(RefreshService.class.getName(), "onUnbind");
    return true;
}

public void refreshNext() {

    scheduleNext();

}

public void refresh() {

    Log.i("RefreshService", "Refreshing");

    refreshWidgets();

    scheduleNext();

}

public void doWork() {

    doTheWork();

    scheduleNextPost();

}

private void doTheWork() {

    Log.d("RefreshService", "Refreshing ");


}



/**
 * Note: The point of doing this here is to allow user control over the
 * update frequency
 */
private void refreshWidgets() {

}

private void scheduleNext() {
    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


    long defaufaultFrequency = getLong(
                getResources().getText(R.string.refresh_frequency_default)
                        .toString(), 30000);

    handler.postDelayed(refresher, preferences.getLong(getResources()
                .getText(R.string.refresh_frequency_key).toString(),
                defaufaultFrequency));

}

private void scheduleNextPost() {
    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


    handler.postDelayed(worker,
                preferences
                        .getLong(
                                getResources().getText(
                                        R.string.post_frequency_key)
                                        .toString(),
                                getLong(getResources().getText(
                                        R.string.post_frequency_default)
                                        .toString(), 30000)));


}



private long getLong(String string, long defaultValue) {
    long number;
    try {
        number = Long.parseLong(string);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        number = defaultValue;
    }
    return number;
}

private int getInt(String string, int defaultValue) {
    int number;
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(string);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        number = defaultValue;
    }
    return number;
}

protected void processStatus(Integer status) {

}


}
```

Comment: what if I called startService() from the onDestroy() of each of the services? such as: startService(new IntentServ1.this, Serv1.class))

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand your answer Skywalker. Could you please explain a bit.

Comment: The bove should be running as a service. The service starts doWork(), and when it has run it schedules the next run. In this example the next run is read from the string-resource R.string.post_frequency_default. You can hardcode it if you like. I am using this service to check if the phone has got connection to internet. If it has connection to internet, it will do a post to the server. In your case you should edit the doWork() and the scheduleNextPost().

Answer (score 0):

does it seem viable to add the following to the Serv1 class?

```
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent reStart = new Intent(Serv1.this, Serv1.class);
    startService(reStart);
}
```